# How to assign the same array of columns to multiple dataframes in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have 9 data sets. Between any 2 given data sets, they will share about 60-80% of the same columns. I want to concatenate these data sets into one data set. Due to some memory limitations, I can't load these datasets into data frames and use the concatenate function in pandas (but I can load each individual data set into a data frame). Instead, I am looking at an alternative solution.

I have created an ordered list of all columns which exist in these data sets. And I want to apply this column list to each of the individual 9 data sets. This way they will all have the same columns and are in the same order. Once that is done I will do a concatenate function on the flat files in the terminal, which will essentially append each data sets together, hopefully solving my issue and creating one single dataset of these 9.

The problem I am having is applying the ordered list to 9 data sets. I keep getting a KeyError "[[list of columns]] not in index" whenever I try to change the columns in the single data sets.

This is what I have been trying:
`df = df[clist]`

I have also tried
`df = df.reindex(columns=clist)`
but this doesn't create the extra columns in the data frame, it just orders them in the order that clist is in.

I expect the result to create 9 datasets which lineup on the same axis for an appends or concat operation outside pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it.

the reindiex function does work. I was applying the reindex function outside of the list of dataframes I had created.

I loaded these 9 datasets with their first 9 rows into a list.

```
for filename in all_files:
       df = pd.read(filename,nrows=10)
       li.append(df)
```

And from that list I used the reindex as such

```
for i in range(0,9):
        li[i]=li[i].reindex(columns=clist)
```